# Joins in Oracle: Which field on which side of an = sign?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, ansi-92

When joining tables with either the ANSI-89 (old) or the ANSI-92 ("new") method of joining tables, does it matter which side you place the fields from the 2 joining tables.

For example, is it better to do:

```
From 
TABLE_1 A

Join
TABLE_2 B
    on A.ID = B.ID
```

Or is the following better?

```
    on B.ID = A.ID
```

Is it simply aesthetics?  Or does it effect how the joins work?

EDIT: For further clarification, what about Left Joins? For example:

```
From
TABLE_1 A

Left Join
TABLE_2 B
    on A.ID = B.ID
```

Is this the same as

```
    on B.ID = A.ID
```

However, if using ANSI-89 `Where A.ID = B.ID (+)` is NOT the same as `Where B.ID = A.ID (+)` since the second joins A ONTO B?

Comment: The `(+)` is supposed to be applied to the column that is on the outer-joined table, so it should be `A.ID = B.ID(+)` vs. `B.ID(+) = A.ID`. And yes, it doesn't matter which way you put them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference.  The only time the order matters is when you are doing LEFT and RIGHT OUTER joins, but those keywords all fall before the ON keyword.

Comment: I'll update the original question, but if you have a Left Join, and do `B.ID = A.ID`, are you saying it still works the same as `A.ID = B.ID` in ANSI-92?  But with ANSI-89 it DOES matter the order (ie `A.ID = B.ID (+)` is not the same as `B.ID = A.ID (+)` since it indicates you are joining A ONTO B, instead of B ONTO A?

Comment: Yes, in every case, the A.ID = B.ID is interchangeable with B.ID = A.ID, there is nothing beyond aesthetics in that choice.

I probably shouldn't have mentioned LEFT JOIN.

FROM Table_1 A LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 B will be different than FROM Table_2 B LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_1 A, but that's unrelated to your question so I should have omitted it.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator is symmetric, so `a.id = b.id` is exactly the same as `b.id = a.id`. Personally, I prefer having the fields from the driving table (the one in the `FROM` clause) on the left hand side of the operator, but that's purely an aesthetic preference.

Comment: I would normally agree, it's looks better when using ANSI-89.  However, when using ANSI-92, I find that, especially when my From becomes `T1 join T2 on T2.ID = T1.ID and T2.TYPE = 'X' and T2.DATE = sysdate` etc, it becomes easier to recognize what table is being used.